# is there are AD sizer tool available for windows server 2008

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is there any AD sizer tool available for windows 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the Windows 2000 era [Active Directory Sizer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=77c0a895-3dfc-469f-be40-6a0ee594821c&displaylang=en) is relevant any more. Your best bet is to download the Active Directory Domain Services Guide from Microsoft's [Infrastructure Planning and Design](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=AD3921FB-8224-4681-9064-075FDF042B0C&displaylang=en#filelist) site.

Step D1: Determine Domain Controller Configuration is the section that has guidance on sizing of Domain Controllers.

Comment: No worries. Have a look at the rest of the guide as there is some good info in there on AD Planning and Design.